# Value returned from set command always empty

Tags: batch-file

I have the following Windows batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION ENABLEEXTENSIONS
cd "C:\Users\jgsyl_000\Music\iTunes\iTunes Media\Music\"

for /d  %%G in (*) do (
    Pushd %%G
    rem Echo now in %%G
    for /D %%a in (*) do (
        pushd %%a
        rem Echo now in %%a
        dir /B > tempfile.txt
        set /p teste=< tempfile.txt
        echo "%teste%"
        TaggerSharp.exe "%teste%" -b >> "C:\Users\jgsyl_000\Music\Statistics\Albums.txt"
        del tempfile.txt
        popd
    )   
    Popd
)
```

The specific problem is the result of the `set /p teste = < tempfile.txt`. When I run this from this batch file, the value is always an empty string. When I run the set command from a separate batch file out side any loop, it works fine. Any suggestion as to what I am missing?

Comment: Did you try `!teste!` in place of `%teste%` ?

Comment: As you are using variables within the for loops, you need to use ! instead of % (as @SachaDee said) so that the variables are looked up as the line is executed and not pre-loaded when the for loop is parsed. This is called delayed expansion - hence your setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION. Other things I see that you may want to look into: Your dir /b will return directories and files. Your set /p line will only take the first entry for the tempfile. Tempfile.txt may also end up listed in itself. You might want to make the 1st `for /r /d` and the 2nd `for` for the files.

Comment: Scott:Thanks for the tip. And it works like a champ! I must have been looking at this much too long. I will also investigate your other suggestion. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I have received two answers to my question: 1) from @SachaDee and 2) @Scott C. I am unable to respond or comment directly to @SachaDee. I returned a comment to @Scott C. I cannot find any checkmark that the site's help says to press to mark my question as answered, so I am answering my own question. Maybe the moderator can respond and close this question as answer by @SachaDee and @Scott C

Answer (score 0):

Will this work by using a escape caracter (^)?

```
set /p teste=^< tempfile.txt
```

Also you may have to replace %teste% with !teste!

Comment: I tried this and it does not work for me. The solution to my problem, is, as you suggest, using !teste!. Thanks,